# How to make view.getDrawingCache() preserving transparency

Tags: android

If I have a view with a transparent background and I do `bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();`, that bitmap is unfortunately **no more transparent**. A black background is set in background.

I have even tried

`view.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

without success.

Actually this method allows to set the background color without any alpha support, `Color.TRANSPARENT` which is `0x00000000` is actually black if you don't care about the alpha part...
If I use `Color.RED`, the background is indeed *very* red.

Any idea to make this work? Is this a limitation of current Android API? Can I use draw() instead? but it's less performant that this `view.getDrawingCache()` I suppose (no cache)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you found a solution ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I also get image with black background by calling `getDrawingCache()` method. Actually, the image has transparent background. Mistake is saving the image in **jpeg format**, so the gallery app shows transparent pixels in black color.

If you put it as an overlay, it'll work perfectly. There is no issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Draw caching is somewhat of a relic of pre-HW-accelerated Android, so some stuff might be a bit confusing/not as well documented.

Transparency should work just fine as long as you leave out `View#setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(int)` as this might cause the cache to drop down to 16 bit color space (see [View#mDrawingCacheBackgroundColor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java?av=f#3372)).

This code

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
// wait for first layout
...
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
```

should give you an ARGB_8888 bitmap with transparent background. (You can also this in the Android Studio debugger by settings a breakpoint after the get call and 'View Bitmap' on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after setting the layout background color transparent in XML file

```
            layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bmp = layout.getDrawingCache();
            File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "smiley1.png");
            FileOutputStream outStream;
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
```